# Change logger at runtime

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to log to a certain layout if a boolean variable is set to true in my code, else log with another layout.

For the moment I have a simple XML that looks kind of like this :

```xml
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="false">

    <appender name="console1" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console2" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                    value="%-5p %m"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

What I'd like to do is to log with the console1 layout is `date == true`, and log with console2 layout if `date == false`.

Is is possible to override getLogger? Is there something that I can do in the xml file to communicate with the boolean variable? I have not succeeded in any of those two methods...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Pattern Selectors**.

The [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) can be configured with a `PatternSelector` to allow it to choose a pattern to use based on attributes of the log event or other factors. A `PatternSelector` will normally be configured with a defaultPattern attribute, which is used when other criteria don't match, and a set of `PatternMatch` elements that identify the various patterns that can be selected.

**MarkerPatternSelector**

The `MarkerPatternSelector` selects patterns based on the `Marker` included in the log event. If the `Marker` in the log event is equal to or is an ancestor of the name specified on the `PatternMatch` key attribute, then the pattern specified on that `PatternMatch` element will be used.

```
<PatternLayout>
  <MarkerPatternSelector defaultPattern="[%-5level] %c{1.} %msg%n">
    <PatternMatch key="FLOW" pattern="[%-5level] %c{1.} ====== %C{1.}.%M:%L %msg ======%n"/>
  </MarkerPatternSelector>
</PatternLayout>
```

Comment: The thing is I'm setting `private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger()` in many different function across my code.
Ideally in my main function I'd have something that would say "from now on when i call `getLogger`, it must return the logger `console1` or `console2`.
If I can make that happen with PatternMatching I'd be glad to do so, but I don't see how.

Comment: Do you want different layouts or different appenders? Because your comment suggests you want a different appender whereas your question specifically mentions layout.

Comment: You're right, I'm not making myself clear.  To avoid X Y problem : what I'm trying to do, is to log with a layout containing ANSI colors if `System.console()` returns true ; and log WITHOUT colors if `System.console()` returns false;
So it's not dependent on the log level, but on a boolean value that's in my code. The `System.console` gets called once in the init process in my main.

Comment: In that case, you should define two loggers and use them based on if condition in code.
Define a logger like this:
`<Logger name="Console1" level="info" additivity="false">
 <AppenderRef ref="console1" />
</Logger>`

Comment: Thanks! You rock! :D